# Set language for ads in Admob

Tags: cordova, admob, phonegap

So on this page https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2784738?hl=en they mention the following
"AdMob will serve relevant ads to your apps in the appropriate language".

How exactly is this accomplished and how can I control (for all users) which language the ads appear in?

Using cordova with the admob plugin.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I found no option in the admob settings so I guess one would have to define it in javascript or html

Comment: Are you using the SDK? Your question will have to relate to that.

Comment: I updated the question. I am using the cordova plugin.

Comment: you can use plugin admob pro .. you can choise language and more option ..

Comment: @Younes I can not find any information regarding that. Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

AdMob handles this for you. The Mobile Ads SDK will automatically look at the device's language settings and use that when choosing an ad to display. There is not, to my knowledge, any way for publishers to force the SDK to use any particular language.